# Getting Error Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_sqlite3_prepare_v3" React Native Firebase

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm quite newbie with RN and ios plattform.. So far, I follow the instruction to install the pods and firebase.. Everything works well.. But i keep getting error (refer to pic below)

here's link for my error image:

[image]

Anyone know how to solve this? Thank you in advance

Here is some of my environment:

```
Environment:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
  Node: 10.6.0
  Yarn: 1.16.0
  npm: 6.9.0
  Watchman: Not Found
  Xcode: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
  Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.3.0-alpha.1 => 16.3.0-alpha.1
  react-native: 0.54.1 => 0.54.1
```

```c
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <Firebase.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"EEA"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

@end
```